# An application of heat transform leads to a specific pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I just see this pde: $$u_t=\epsilon^2u_{xx}-u,\ \ 0<\epsilon<<1 \\
\text{with conditions:}\ \ \ \ \ \ \     u(x,0)=1-x,\ u(0,t)=1,\ u(1,t)=0$$

and would like to know how it can be derived from a specific heat transfer problem. I plot this pde numerically in Matlab and it shows me the formation of a boundary layer near $x=0$[image] as time increases from 0. So can anyone help me an application of heat transfer leads to having this form of a pde? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: There is no stochastic PDE in this question